# Excel - How to combine columns (without concatenating them) from multiple files

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge, column

I have multiple CSV files, each containing several columns, but only one of interest, column B. It's a column whose header is "Results" and each row in the column contains numeric data.
For example, here's: "file 1":

| undefined | Results |
| --- | --- |
| (empty) | 10.5 |
| (empty) | 28.3 |

My desired outcome is a single sheet that has all column Bs of all those files.

| Results (from file 1) | Results (from file 2) | Results (from file 3) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.5 | 23.5 | 7 |
| 28.3 | 11.1 | 8.9 |

I have managed to user Power Query to create this output:

| Results |
| --- |
| 10.5 |
| 28.3 |
| ... |
| Results |
| 23.5 |
| 11.1 |
| Results |
| 7 |
| 8.9 |

Which is missing two things:

First, I can't tell which data came from which file. I would like the headers to have the file name, or at least part of it.

Second, this is not the desired output format - I would want to split this column into multiple columns. This is not a typical split scenario from what I have seen, so the built-in 'Split column' or 'Text to column' didn't work, or I did not configure them right.

Comment: Hard to know what you did wrong without your code and more information.  If you select multiple CSV files (for example, from a folder) and use the Combine option, a column is added with the original file name.  Then it's just a matter of doing a Pivot with no aggregation.

Comment: You can try to provide the result table you need here, it will more clearly to help you